# Japanese student learning Chinese characters?

Tags: kanji, orthography, chinese

I've recently started to self-study Japanese. Some time ago I thought of studying Mandarin Chinese and bought a book (Tuttle Learning Chinese Characters, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/805242.Learning_Chinese_Characters) to learn the characters. But after having a go at both Chinese and Japanese, I decided to stick with the latter.

So far I understand that most Kanji are derived directly from the Chinese writing system, that the meanings are usually the same or very similar and that changed pronunciation is the trickiest bit. My book does present the traditional form (which, to my knowledge, is the form used in Japanese...?) of a character together with the simplified one.

I'd like to know whether it'd be a good idea to continue using the material I bought or whether I should rather get a similar book for Japanese instead. And if so, could anyone recommend me a good one?

Comment: Japanese kanji are not the same as either traditional or simplified Chinese, so it's not 100% accurate to say it's written like traditional Chinese.  There are some simplifications used in Japanese writing as well.  In any case, you'll need to study kanji specifically in the context of Japanese to become literate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry if my question wasn't appropriate for the website. I'll take a look at the learning resources section now.